# SPI using STM32's DMA sends one word too much

Tags: stm32, spi, stm32f10x, dma

On an STM32F103 I configure SPI in 16bit wide mode and set up a DMA transfer to transmit **one** byte:

```
SPI2->CR1 &= ~SPI_CR1_SPE;
SPI2->CR2 = 0;
SPI2->CR1 =
    SPI_CR1_SSM |
    SPI_CR1_SSI |
    SPI_CR1_DFF |
    SPI_CR1_SPE |
    /* Some baud rate flags */ |
    SPI_CR1_MSTR;

/* Set up DMA transfers */
DMA1_Channel4->CMAR = (uint32_t) /* some buffer */;
DMA1_Channel4->CPAR = (uint32_t) &SPI2->DR;
DMA1_Channel4->CNDTR = 1;
DMA1_Channel4->CCR = DMA_CCR4_MINC | DMA_CCR4_EN;

uint16_t dummy = 0xFFFF;
DMA1_Channel5->CMAR = (uint32_t) &dummy;
DMA1_Channel5->CPAR = (uint32_t) &SPI2->DR;
DMA1_Channel5->CNDTR = 1;
DMA1_Channel5->CCR = DMA_CCR5_DIR | DMA_CCR5_EN;

/* Transfer */
SPI2->CR1 |= SPI_CR1_SPE;
DMA1->IFCR = DMA_IFCR_CTCIF5 | DMA_IFCR_CTCIF4;
SPI2->CR2 |= SPI_CR2_TXDMAEN | SPI_CR2_RXDMAEN;
SPI2->CR1 |= SPI_CR1_SPE;
```

I connected a counter to the SPI's clock line and the above code produces **32 clocks**. No interrupts are enabled or whatsoever; the behaviour can constantly be observed. If the DMA is set up to transmit zero bytes, no clocks are generated.

Why does it clock out 32 bits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Discovered the issue: The SPI's CRC unit has been enabled by accident, so the excess transfer stems from the CRC checksum. This was impossible to deduct from the above source; enabling CRC happened somewhere else and I missed it.

Answer (score 2):

It's because the code tells the SPI to receive one word via DMA channel 4 and transmit one word via DMA channel 5 and then both channels are enabled simultaneously. Most likely enabling the DMA reception already triggers a transfer as well. Try enabling only one of TXDMAEN or RXDMAEN bits.

Comment: When I instruct both DMAs to transfer 200 bytes then the above example will transfer 201 bytes... But nevertheless, I will examine your suggestion asap.

Comment: It was the CRC :-/ Question obsoleted...